# Can I safely get a c_str out of std::stringstream in c++?

Tags: c++, reference, pass-by-reference, lifetime

I am working with a C function that takes a string (i.e. a pointer to a null terminated array of char) and does stuff with it internally. It **does not**, however, keep a reference to the string after the function returns.

I want to pass it some formatted input, so I am using a `std::stringstream`. In order to keep my code cleaner -- and because this pattern repeats throughout the codebase, I want to simply pass `ss.str().c_str()`.

To me this seems scary because I'm calling a method on the temporary `ss.str()`, but I think it's ok because of lifetime extension. Namely, the standard says:

> A temporary bound to a reference parameter in a function call (5.2.2) persists until the completion of the full expression containing the call [...] In all these cases, the temporaries created during the evaluation of the expression initializing the reference, except the temporary to which the reference is bound, are destroyed **at the end of the full-expression** in which they are created and in the reverse order of the completion of their construction.

(emphasis mine)

As such, I would expect my values to stick around until the C API call ends. Am I mistaken? Is this safe to do? Conceptually, my code looks as follows:

```cpp
void g(int x, int y) {
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << "(" << x << ", " << y << ")";
    puts(ss.str().c_str());
}
```

Comment: "The end of the full expression" is the `;` following `puts` here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes that's fine, and `ss.str().c_str()` crops up quite often when working with C-style APIs.

Informally speaking, the anonymous temporary `std::string` returned from `ss.str()` survives the `puts()` function call. This means that the `const char*` pointer returned by `c_str()` remains valid for the duration of `puts()`.

What you *can't* do is:

```
const char* ub = ss.str().c_str();
puts(ub);
```

as the pointer `ub` is dangling.